# How to retrieve images path from database and display images path in thumbnail like photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming.I have stored images path in database.Now i want to retrieve that images path and after that using that path i want to display images in thumbnail,like photo gallery images.And i can able retrieve that images path from database,i have stored that images path in array,now i want to display all images in thumbnail how to do this.Can any body help me.

Thanks

Comment: which path bundle path or asset library path ?

Answer (score 0):

For `iOS 6` and above I would suugest to use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177) and [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

The goal is to use `PSTCollectionView` on `iOS 4/5` as a fallback and switch to `UICollectionView` on iOS6. We even use certain runtime tricks to create `UICollectionView` at runtime for older versions of iOS. Ideally, you just link the files and everything works on older systems.

**Otherwise** ,use [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) OR [ZZGridView](http://www.zubizubilabs.com/zzgridview.html)